# how to get the content between the first html tag and the second html tag in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, html

Hi friend~
I want get the content between the first html tag and the second html tag.
for example
`<p>Hello <bold>world</bold>!</p>`
will return
`Hello`

What should I do in Ruby?
Thank you~

Comment: Have you tried Nokogiri? it's a lot easier than using regexes to parse HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex will be: `<[^>]*>([^<]*)`

1. `<[^>]*>` - math thiw first tag "<...>"
2. `([^<]*)` - capture text to open next tag "<...> **some text** <...>"

how apply him on Rubby - i dont know

look http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression catching everthing between the first and the second pair of angle brackets lools like

```
/<.*?>(.*?)</m
```

The result will be in the first capturing group of the first match.

Note that this will probably fail on HTML comments and JavaScript.